# jquery $.parseXML cannot parse XML from php strings?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

Somehow I keep getting error in javascript when I try to parse xml from php string, my code is like:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$products = $xml->xpath("/products/product[@model='".$model . "']");
$filtered_xml = $products[0]->asXML();
?>

<script> 
alert( $.parseXML( '<?php echo $filtered_xml;?>'  ).find('name').text() );
</script>
```

`echo $filtered_xml` is returning a well formed xml as I am looking for, but something in the javascript - `$.parseXML( '<?php echo $filtered_xml;?>'  )` is causing errors. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you specify the error you are getting?

Comment: can you show the markup rendered on the browser?

Comment: it's not executing the php i bet. use double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

$.parseXML() itself does not return a jQuery object. Look at example in docs

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Proper use in your case would look more like:

```
  var xml= $.parseXML( '<?php echo $filtered_xml;?>') ;

   alert( $(xml).find('name').text() )
```